# How can I add other data after the resulting query

Tags: php, datatables-1.10

I have this query.

```
 $stmt = $this->getconnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM detailuser where id = ?");
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and I want to add amount in the result after the dateadded, but I am confuse how to add the amount. the amount is in another table and I have no reference on the first table (detailuser)

$amount = 100;

```
$rec = array(
                'data'=>$result,


            );

echo json_encode($rec);

{"data":[{"firstname":"Alex","friendname":"Alice","amount_due":"600.00","dateadded"
:"2015-09-14 13:30"},{"firstname":"Annie","friendname":"Karren","amount_due":"600
.00","dateadded":"2015-09-14 13:30"},{"firstname":"Helen","friendname":"Alice","amount_due":"600.00","dateadded":"2015-09-14 13:30"}]}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can prepare a `SELECT` statement to fetch all rows and in that statement, you can add your dummy column.

`SELECT *, 100 AS 'amount' FROM table_name`

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO prepare and then fetchAll() results!

```
$stmt= $dbh->prepare("SELECT firstname, friendname, amount_due, dateadded, "100" AS amount FROM yourTable");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of abusing your `SELECT` statement you can also loop over your result set.

```
foreach ( $result as $row ){
    $row['amount'] = 100;
}
//encode and output
```